# Signalr calling specific client from outside the hub

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm aware of the [Chris Fulstow project log4net.signalr](https://github.com/ChrisFulstow/log4net.SignalR), it is a great idea if you want a non production log since it logs all messages from all requests. I would like to have something that discriminates log messages by the request originating them and sed back to the proper browser.

Here what I've done in the appender:

```
 public class SignalRHubAppender:AppenderSkeleton
    {
        protected override void Append(log4net.Core.LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current != null)
            {
                var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["log-id"];
                if (null != cookie)
                {
                    var formattedEvent = RenderLoggingEvent(loggingEvent);
                    var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<Log4NetHub>();
                    context.Clients[cookie.Value].onLog(new { Message = formattedEvent, Event = loggingEvent });
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to attach the session id to a cookie, but this does not work on the same machine because the cookie is overwritten. 
here is the code I use on the client to attach the event:

```
//start hubs
    $.connection.hub.start()
    .done(function () {
        console.log("hub subsystem running...");
        console.log("hub connection id=" + $.connection.hub.id);
        $.cookie("log-id", $.connection.hub.id);
        log4netHub.listen();
    });
```

As a result, just the last page connected shows the log messages. I would like to know if there is some strategies to have the current connection id from the browser which originate the current request, if there is any.
Also I'm interested to know if there is better design to achieve a per browser logging.

**EDIT**

I could made a convention name based cookie ( like log-id-someguid ), but I wonder if there is something smarter.

**BOUNTY**
I decided to start a bounty on that  question, and I would additionally ask about the architecture, in order to see if my strategy makes sense or not.
My doubt is, I'm using the hub in a single "direction" from server to client, and I use it to log activities not originating from calls to the hub, but from other requests ( potentially requests raised on other hubs ), is that a correct approach, having as a goal a browser visible log4net appender?

Comment: I never had to solve such an issue, the only way that comes out of my mind is to have some url rewriting, so that each browser/tab instance is uniquely identified via the url, or a combination of both url and cookies

Comment: @Wasp problem the app is an SPA :) I edit the question to propose an additional idea to see if it make sense

Comment: I guessed it :)  But still I think you could come up with some smart routing rule to have a sort of unique id generated in the url and handled in some way. Stupid idea, the user goes to http://www.foo.com, and you redirect him on first connection to http://www.foo.com/n2998fhn239, and keep it there in your SPA

Comment: @Wasp nice idea, I'm little afraid that the wole architecture is incorrect. But other sample about the same topic does not discriminates between client sessions.

Comment: I think it's the only solution which works with any (non jurassic) browser. Combining some generated cookie and the url you should be able to prevent hijacking, and at that point SignalR does the rest. I can't find corner cases, but maybe it's just me :)

Comment: What about just generating a GUID in javascript and setting it as the cookie value instead of the SignalR connection id? That would solve the problem where only the last page gets messages (which is obviously because SignalR starts a new connection on every page and overwrites the cookie). Instead of a GUID you could also just use the ASP.NET Session ID. *Edit* forgot to mention you'd need to add the connection to a SignalR Group identified by the cookie value for this to work.

Comment: @akoeplinger even if I use a GUID as a cookie value, wouldn't be the cookie overwritten as well if I open another browser at the same url ?

Comment: Yes, but you can check if the cookie is already set and do nothing in this case, or am I missing something in your scenario?

Comment: @akoeplinger if I launch two browser instances, both should log...

Comment: You can set the expiration date of the cookie to a date far in the future, e.g. 2038. If you open multiple instances of the same browser application, they'll use the same cookie and both should receive the messages (assuming you've added the connection to a group identified by the cookie value on the server).

Comment: I guess Felice does NOT want that all the instances with the same cookie receive that message, each one should receive only the messages is some way related to that particular instance. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea about how to correctly target the right browser instance/tab, even when multiple tabs are open on the same SPA, is to differentiate them through the Url. One possible way to implement that is to redirect them at the first access from http://foo.com to http://foo.com/hhd83hd8hd8dh3, randomly generated each time. That url rewriting could be done in other ways too, but it's just a way to illustrate the problem. This way the appender will be able to inspect the originating Url, and from the Url through some mapping you keep server side you can identify the right SignalR ConnectionId. The implementation details may vary, but the basic idea is this one. Tracking some more info available in the HttpContext since the first connection you could also put in place additional strategies in order to prevent any hijacking.

About your architecture, I can tell you that this is exactly the way I used it in [ElmahR](http://elmahr.apphb.com/). I have messages originating from outside the notification hub (errors posted from other web apps), and I do a broadcast to all clients connected to that hub (and subscribing certain groups): it works fine.

I'm not an authoritative source, but I also guess that such an architecture is ok, even with multiple hubs, because hubs at the end of the day are just an abstraction over a (one) persistent connection which allows you to group messaging by contexts. Behind the scenes (I'm simplifying) you have just a persistent connection with messages going back and forth, so whatever hub structure you define on top of it (which is there just to help you organizing things) you still insist on that connection, so you cannot do any harm.

SignalR is good on doing 2 things: massive broadcast (Clients), and one-to-one communication (Caller). As long as you do not try to do weird things like building keeping server-side references to specific callers, you should be ok, whatever number of Hubs, and interactions among them, you have.

These are my conclusions, coming from the field. Maybe you can twit @dfowler about this question and see if he has (much) more authoritative guidelines.

Comment: I'm happy hearing the overall architecture make sense, still looking for something better than cookies to direct messages to the proper source